# Android app crashes No virtual method readAllBytes()

Tags: java, android, arrays, inputstream

We have reported some crashes from Android 9 and 10 devices when they try to read pdf file with this method:

```
fun getPdfImageFromUri(uri: Uri?, applicationContext: Context): String? {
    var outputString: String? = null

    uri?.let {
        ByteArrayOutputStream().apply {
            outputString = encodeToString(applicationContext.contentResolver.openInputStream(it)?.readAllBytes())
        }
    }

    return outputString
}
```

and crash report:
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No virtual method readAllBytes()[B in class Ljava/io/InputStream; or its super classes (declaration of 'java.io.InputStream' appears in /apex/com.android.art/javalib/core-oj.jar)

what could cause this problem ? Seems like it works fine on Android 11-13

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code:

```
fun getPdfImageFromUri(uri: Uri?, applicationContext: Context): String? {
    var outputString: String? = null

    uri?.let {
        val inputStream = applicationContext.contentResolver.openInputStream(it)
        val bytes = if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            inputStream?.readAllBytes()
        } else {
            inputStream?.readBytes()
        }
        outputString = encodeToString(bytes)
    }

    return outputString
}
```

The problem was caused by the use of the `readAllBytes()` method, which was introduced in **Java 9**. This method is not available on *Android 9 and 10 devices*, causing the java.lang.NoSuchMethodError to be thrown when the code is run on those devices.
Here are some links that support this information:

- [When to use the readAllBytes() method of InputStream in Java 9](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/when-to-use-the-readallbytes-method-of-inputstream-in-java-9)